# AWSのElasticBeanstalkで作成したインスタンスを別VPCに移行したい。

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, vpc, aws-elasticbeanstalk

ネットワークの整理をすることになったため、VPC間の移動を行いたいのですが、
ElasticBeanstalkで作成したEC2やRDS、ELBを別VPCに移行させることは可能でしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalkには設置先のVPCを後から変更する機能は無かったと思います。
ですので、新しく環境(Enviroment)を作成してそこに移行する事になると思います。

アプリケーション自体はデプロイしなおすだけなので簡単かと思います。

Elatic BeanstalkでRDSも管理されていて、停止時間が許容されるなら、RDSのスナップショットを取得しておき新しい環境を作成時にそのスナップショットを指定すればよいかと思います。